# git pull pushed commits to remote branch

Tags: git, github

I ran `git pull origin redesign` yesterday and found that my commits on my local branch were somehow pushed to the remote branch. The git pull found that everything was up-to-date and did not need to merge the code from the remote branch. I should note that on my local machine I was on the same branch titled `redesign`. How could a git pull also push my commits to the remote branch? I don't think this has ever happened before. What could be wrong? All other git commands appear to be working fine.

Comment: Can't you just look at the log of the remote branch and see when and by whom the changes were committed?

Comment: Yes. They were made by me at the time of the `git pull`. I did not run a `git push origin redesign` at that time. I knew immediately that commits were made when I ran git pull. I was the only one working on the remote branch.

Answer (score 0):

> How could a git pull also push my commits to the remote branch?

It cannot.

> What could be wrong?

Either your local changes got lost (unlikely, you would probably have noticed that...) or pushed to the remote in some other fashion. Maybe you were in another branch and did `git push --all`?

Comment: I did run a `git push other_remote redesign` but that has never updated the `origin` remote. I looked up the entire history of my bash commands and at no time was `git push origin redesign` called.

Comment: Thanks anyways. It was worth a shot.